# ¿Hay un error al visualizar un proyecto en el navegador?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo una hoja de estilos (CSS) en la cual tengo varios media queries y según lo que he investigado si se encuentra bien estructurado; a continuación les presento una imagen de la misma:

[image: hoja de estilos]

y en el html tengo la línea del meta que es indispensable:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

ya cuando corro en el navegador (específicamente en Google Chrome) como estoy en una pantalla de 1920px de ancho al momento de redimensionar la ventana del navegador no se adapta a las media queries que se especifica en la hoja de css.

Saben que puede estar originando este error ya que en un javascript si utilizo el `$(window).scroll(function() {...}`

Les agradezco mucho ya que hasta el momento no encuentro una solución por más que estoy viendo tutoriales sobre las media queries.

Comment: Cuando redimensionas la ventana del navegador para ver como se adapta el diseño estas forzando una situación anómala. En la realidad el navegador renderiza una u otra resolución. Si dejas un ancho y recargas lo que verás es más realista que al cambiar el tamaño arrastrando, situación en la que algunos estilos no se renderizan correctamente.

Comment: y hay alguna forma de controlar esto con algún atributo del dom?